# Individual timeouts for concurrent.futures

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I see two ways to specify timeouts in [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html).

- `as_completed()`
- `wait()`

Both methods handle N running futures.

I would like to specify an individual timeout for each future.

Use Case:

- Future for getting data from DB has a timeout of 0.5 secs.
- Future for getting data from a HTTP server has a timeout of 1.2 secs.

How do I handle this with `concurrent.futures`? Or is this library not the right tool?

## Conclusion

- AFAIK the solution by mdurant is a good work-around.
- I think I will use a different library the next time. Maybe asyncio has better support for this. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about implementing your own:

```
wait(dbfutures + httpfutures, timeout=0.5)
[fut.cancel() for fut in bdfutures if not fut.done()]
wait(httpfutures, timeout=0.7)
[fut.cancel() for fut in httpfutures if not fut.done()]
```

(or a while loop with sleep/check or wait with short timeout)

Comment: Yes, I think this is the only solution. Not nice, but a working work-around. I think I will use async io the next time: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep