# What is the purpose of `concurrent.futures.Future.result` `timeout` argument?

Tags: python, timeout, concurrent.futures

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result):

> If the call hasn’t yet completed then this method will wait up to timeout seconds. If the call hasn’t completed in timeout seconds, then a TimeoutError will be raised.

But clearly this is a False statement and doesn't represent the actual behavior:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import sleep


def my_worker(sleep_time, expected_timeout):
    sleep(sleep_time)
    print(f'slept for {sleep_time} | expected timeout: {expected_timeout}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    timeout = 1
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(my_worker, 3, timeout)]
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            future.result(timeout=timeout)
```

which results in:

```
slept for 3 | expected timeout: 1
```

There are other questions addressing a [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420758/concurrent-futures-threadpoolexecutor-map-timeout-not-working) of the same issue with `concurrent.futures` objects, but none provide any clarification of the `timeout` argument in `Future.result`.

Even the `timeout` argument in `concurrent.futures.as_completed` mentioned in the other questions is not working as expected. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed):

> The returned iterator raises a TimeoutError if **next**() is called and the result isn’t available after timeout seconds from the original call to as_completed(). timeout can be an int or float.

This sets me to expect a timeout exception is to be raised after whatever `timeout` is specified of `as_completed` call, disregarding how many tasks are pending. This also doesn't work as expected:

```
timeout = 1
with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(my_worker, 3, timeout) for _ in range(5)]
    for future in as_completed(futures, timeout):  # should timeout after one second
        future.result()
```

What actually happens: `as_completed` ignores the timeout and awaits all tasks to finish before raising an error:

```
slept for 3 | expected timeout: 1
slept for 3 | expected timeout: 1
slept for 3 | expected timeout: 1
slept for 3 | expected timeout: 1
slept for 3 | expected timeout: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_file.py", line 16, in <module>
    completed.__next__()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 239, in as_completed
    raise TimeoutError(
TimeoutError: 5 (of 5) futures unfinished
```

Even the error message indicating that 5/5 tasks failed to complete is not true, otherwise these finished - timeout prompts wouldn't have shown.

Answer (score 0):

For the first implementation, you are calling `Future.result` inside `as_completed`. As `timeout` starts from the moment `Future.result` is called, and all threads are already finished by then, no error is raised. If the keyword argument is placed in `as_completed` instead, the exception is thrown as expected.

As for the second implementation, documentation for `ThreadPoolExecutor` says that

```
All threads enqueued to ThreadPoolExecutor will be joined before the interpreter can exit.
```

So the error **is** raised at the expected moment, just that Python waits until all threads are finished before throwing `TimeoutError`.

As a sanity check,

```py
timeout = 1
with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(my_worker, 3, timeout) for _ in range(5)]
    try:
        for future in as_completed(futures, timeout=timeout):  # should timeout after one second
            future.result()
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e).__name__)
        print(e)
```

outputs

```
TimeoutError
5 (of 5) futures unfinished
slept for 3 | expected timeout: 1
slept for 3 | expected timeout: 1
slept for 3 | expected timeout: 1
slept for 3 | expected timeout: 1
slept for 3 | expected timeout: 1
```

And it seems that everything does work according to the documentation. Though I do agree with you that this isn't very intuitive.